# Can't get Guice Injector Instance play 2.5 scalatest

Tags: scala, playframework, guice, scalatest, playframework-2.5

We are using scalatestplus-play 1.5.1 version.

Here is the code snippet for BaseTestClass :

```
trait GuiceMock extends Suite with OneAppPerTest with BeforeAndAfterAll {

    def injector(): Injector = { app.injector }

    override def newAppForTest(testData: TestData): Application = {
        new GuiceApplicationBuilder().configure().configure(configurationMap)
          .disable(classOf[SomeModule], classOf[RedisSentinelModule])
          .bindings(getTestModule())
          .in(Mode.Test).build()
    }
    ...
}
```

In my test I need an instance of injector similar to below :

```
trait ControllerFixture extends MockitoSugar with GuiceMock { 
  ...

  val someClient = injector.instanceOf(classOf[SomeClient])

  ...
}
```

But I am met with a null pointer exception @ this line :

```
 def injector(): Injector = { app.injector }
```

Any pointers ?

Comment: Try using `play.api.Play.current.injector` instead of `app.injector`. Also, I think you can just pass the type to `instanceOf` rather than `classOf[type]`.

Comment: play.api.Play.current.injector is deprecated

Comment: doesn't instanceOf take the Type ? so I have to pass classOf[SomeClient] where SomeClient.scala binding is defined in the TestModule.scala

Comment: If you hvae an entire play app running, then I would pass the `play.api.Application` as implicit to the injector method and then get the injector from there.

Comment: a workaround could be to make your client lazy: `lazy val someClient = ...`, so it wouldn't be initialized when the test suite starts but only when the actual test requires it, and the `app` is defined